# Golang Logical AND of result of function

Tags: go, inline, bitwise-operators

I want to run a function multiple times and then do something if anything failed.

So I set a flag before looping the calls, the called function comes back with a success/failure boolean but, if I use an in-line logical AND, the function is no longer called as though an IF statement exists.  Can someone explain this?

Example in GO Playground (https://go.dev/play/p/I5DP2mDmoqI)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("In-line logical AND")
    resultOK := true
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        resultOK = resultOK && doSomething(i)
    }

    fmt.Println("Separate line for logical AND")
    resultOK = true
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        result := doSomething(i)
        resultOK = resultOK && result
    }

}

func doSomething(i int) bool {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界", i)
    return i%2 == 0

}
```

Resulting output

```
In-line logical AND
Hello, 世界0 :  true
Hello, 世界1 :  false
 :  false
 :  false
 :  false
 :  false
 :  false
 :  false
 :  false
 :  false
Separate line for logical AND
Hello, 世界0 :  true
Hello, 世界1 :  false
Hello, 世界2 :  false
Hello, 世界3 :  false
Hello, 世界4 :  false
Hello, 世界5 :  false
Hello, 世界6 :  false
Hello, 世界7 :  false
Hello, 世界8 :  false
Hello, 世界9 :  false
```

Comment: There is no IF statement, look at the two versions of code - the end result should be the same - the only difference is I have an intermediate variable

Comment: It's not about whether there's an `if` or not. From the perspektive of Go, you're interested in the value of `result`, so it would just decrease the performance to continue the evaluation once the result is set. You'll find this this behavior in most other modern languages as well. For good reasons: 1) because of the gain in performance, 2) because what you're doing is relying on a side effect, which should be avoided anyway - it makes the code less reliable, bugs harder to track, tests harder to write and the programm harder to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

If the left operand of the logical AND is `false`, the result will be `false`, so the right operand is not evaluated. In your first example the right operand is the function call, so the function will NOT be called. Similarly, if the first operand of a logical OR is `true`, the result is `true`, so the right operand in that case would not be evaluated either.

This is mentioned in [Spec: Logical operators:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Logical_operators)

> Logical operators apply to [boolean](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Boolean_types) values and yield a result of the same type as the operands. **The right operand is evaluated conditionally.**

In the second example the function is called before the logical AND, so it is called no matter what `resultOK` is.

Comment: Yes I see the logic for a conditional IF but this was really a BOOLEAN AND and not a test.  So I will just put the flag at the end and it will fix it.